# What is Sitecore power user ? Is it normal user with sitecore domain or is it different?

Tags: sitecore

If it is different , can anyone please explain how we can make user, a power user?

Also , code to create a power user .

Comment: Do you mean a Sitecore CMS admin user, there are user roles in Sitecore you can assign roles, or create your own roles, There are also deny rights, so more roles is not necessarily more rights. use the Sitecore domain for you so called power users

Comment: As Jan states, do you mean an admin? Where have you come across the term "power user"?

Comment: Hi Jan , Grahams . I know about sitecore admin but I was specifically asked about "sitecore power user" in one of the interviews perhaps the interviewer wanted to say admin user !

Comment: There is no role specifically called "sitecore power user". I generally give the term power user to some one who's willing/capable of taking on both official Sitecore training and training in the specific implementation from the delivery or support team. They then take this knowledge and mentor/lead the content management team in day to day delivery of content. This user then often has elevated rights if not administrative rights. As mentioned above to give one user more rights then another you do this by applying the appropriate roles to the users Sitecore account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no role specifically called "sitecore power user". I generally give the term power user to some one who's willing/capable of taking on both official Sitecore training and training in the specific implementation from the delivery or support team. They then take this knowledge and mentor/lead the content management team in day to day delivery of content. This user then often has elevated rights if not administrative rights. As mentioned above to give one user more rights then another you do this by applying the appropriate roles to the users Sitecore account